# Include SQLLocalDB into Visual Studio Installer Setup Project

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2017

I'm looking forward how to create an Installer for my application written in C# that can be connected to Server (online-mode) or to a local database (offline-mode). 
What I want to do is an installer package with Visual Studio 2017 that installs the application, the mdf file and, if not installed, the SqlLocalDB.

Do you know how to do it or a good guide/tutorial that explains the right procedure?

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a complicated installation I would like to refer you to [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/) which by far is the most complete feature set of windows installers.
It has a learning curve but you'll not regret your decision later on.

If WiX is your tool of choice, you'll need to use it's Burn bootstrapper feature to install LocalDB as a prerequisite.

```
<MsiPackage SourceFile="SqlLocalDB.msi" Vital="yes" DisplayInternalUI="no">
<MsiProperty Name="ALLUSERS" Value="1"/>
<MsiProperty Name="IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS" Value="YES"/>
```

This guy does it with [sqlexpress](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLz03-JWWQk).

Try tinkering around to make it work with sqllocaldb.msi

Hope it helps

Comment: Dear Hamza, this help for sure. Thanks a lot. My first option is to use the installer included in Visual Studio but is not so clear how to do what I need. Your solution will be a good Plan B :)